# How to identify specific data in a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm doing my first App Scripts and I'm able to have them working... but I remain dependant on some Sheets formulas to identify data. This impacts the speed of my script dramatically.

As a basic example, lets pretend I want to delete every lines that have a "-" in a certain column. I don't know how to identify "-" in a column in App Script so I did this formula in my Helper spreadsheet:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("-",Database!$U:$U,0),0)
```

Then I retrieve this information in my code and recalculate the workbook after each deletion to have the new Match value:

```
function deleteNoValue(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();                 // Thisworkbook
  var ssHlp = ss.getSheetByName('Helper');             // Sheet with match formula
  var ssDb = ss.getSheetByName('Database');            // Sheet to delete lines from
  var firstNoVal = ssHlp.getRange('A1').getValue();    // Match formula value

  while (firstNoVal != 0) {                            // Repeat until all lines deleted
    ssDb.deleteRows(firstNoVal ,1);                    // Delete line
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();                            // Wait for Match to refresh value
    firstNoVal = ssHlp.getRange('A1').getValue();      // Get new value
  }
}
```

How can I have this improved without needing the help of Sheets formulas to be refreshed?

Comment: I don't know how to clarify better than what I explained. The MATCH() formula above is in the Helper sheet and provides the line number to delete in Database sheet

Answer (score 1):

Use [batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations) and `Array.filter()`, like this:

```
function deleteRowsWhereColumnUEqualsDash() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dataRange = ss.getSheetByName('Database').getDataRange();
  const filteredData = dataRange.getValues()
    .filter(row => row[20] !== '-');
  dataRange
    .clearContent()
    .offset(0, 0, filteredData.length, filteredData[0].length)
    .setValues(filteredData);
}
```